# Current directory variable is overwritten in the source files, when there are more files?

Tags: linux, bash

I have been using the following code to get the current directory, in each file I am sourcing. In this way I can source the code path relatively from where I am located. However, this does not look that is working when I have 2 sources as below because $curr is overwritten in the first sourced child file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
curr=$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")
echo $curr
source $curr/bash/index.sh
echo $curr
source $curr/layout.sh
```

Is any alternative or option to what I am trying to do here?

Comment: What about renaming `curr` to something unused in the sourced files? Alternatively, what about not using a variable at all? For example: `source "$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")/bash/index.sh"` and `source "$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")/layout.sh"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the current folder from a script when it's called with source (same shell) or bash (subshell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750794/how-to-read-the-current-folder-from-a-script-when-its-called-with-source-same)

Comment: @user3053247 : Why are you posting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750794/how-to-read-the-current-folder-from-a-script-when-its-called-with-source-same) twice?