# How to read the current folder from a script when it's called with source (same shell) or bash (subshell)?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

This is a hard one, as I have researched for a few hours and could not find a solution that works, so I combined a few of solutions that I found and this is the results:

```
"$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")" )"
```

If anyone has a simpler one, please share otherwise, enjoy!

Comment: See [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Comment: It does not cover what I am saying.

Comment: I believe this is simpler : `"$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" ; echo "$PWD")"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a solution for bash which works in every circumstance (for instance when sourcing a file via a link), but this approach might work most of the time:

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` contains the name of the script including PATH component, in the way it is invoked. If it was invoked via a `$PATH` search, it contains that respective PATH. Hence, `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"` would be the directory, where the script is located (either as relative or absolute path). Consequently, `readlink -f -- $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")` would output the absolute path to this directory. Hence to locate `other_script` in the same directory would be:

```
source "$(readlink -f -- $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"))/other_script" # bash
```

You tagged your question also for *zsh*. In Zsh, things are a bit simpler. You find your script (plus directory part) in `$0`. The absolute path of the directory is hence returned `$0:A`, giving you

```
source $0:A/other_script # zsh
```

Of course, if you need this information only for sourcing the other script, you don't need to get the **absolute** path to `other_script`. The relative path would do as well.